# Gitlab CI with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, gitlab-ci

I have gitlab CI running testing some scripts and I've used the following lines of .gitlab-ci.yml to show the output of MATLAB builds:

```
before_script:

test1:
 script:
   - matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -minimize -wait -logfile matlab-output.txt -r Model
   - type matlab-output.txt
```

This works perfectly when the build is sucessful however not when it fails because the second command doesn't run. I've check gitlab-ci-runner and it doesn't have an 'after_script' option. How'd you tackle this?

Note: this is Windows.

Comment: I'm afraid to use the -nojvm option mentioned because many of the scripts we use have graphics

Comment: Is the script Model writing the file matlab-output.txt despite the failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the long delay and thank you everyone else for helping. I now have a running system using Suever's code. I've modified it to suit MATLAB's Unit framework.

So, finally my .gitlab-ci.yml is:

```
before_script:

Model-01:
  script:
    - cd developers\testModel\01
    - Gitlab_CI_Hook.cmd

Model-02:
  script:
    - cd developers\testModel\02
    - Gitlab_CI_Hook.cmd
```

where Gitlab_CI_Hook.cmd is:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -minimize -wait -logfile matlab-output.txt -r Git_MATLAB_interface
type matlab-output.txt

set content=
for /f "delims=" %%i in (ExitCode.txt) do set content=%content% %%i

exit %content%
```

And Git_MATLAB_interface.m

```
% assume it always fails
exit_code = 1;

% MATLAB runs the test
result = runtests(pwd)

% check the result
if result.Passed ~= 0 && result.Failed == 0 && result.Incomplete == 0
    exit_code = 0;
end

% write the ExitCode
fid = fopen('ExitCode.txt','w');
fprintf(fid,'%d',exit_code);
fclose(fid);

% Ensure that we ALWAYS call exit that is always a success so that CI doesn't stop
exit
```

Answer (score 8):

I think that your issue is two-fold. It's partially because GITLAB doesn't call your `type` statement, but also that the MATLAB process never returns because the script never completes.

For example, type these at the command line:

```
# This one will fail and notice that it never ends
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -minimize -wait -logfile log.txt -r 'disp(a); exit;'
```

This is because MATLAB is never able to execute the `exit` command.

On the other hand, in the case of a success, it is able to reach the `exit` and therefore returns.

```
# This one will pass
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -minimize -wait -logfile log.txt -r 'disp(1); exit;'
```

The way that I actually solve this is two-fold. First, I wrap the command I'm trying to call in a try/catch statement and then convert any errors/exceptions to a string format and display those.

I have this sort of thing within a file called `runtests.m`

```
% runtests.m
exit_code = 0;

try
    Model
catch ME
    disp(getReport(ME))
    exit_code = 1;
end

% Ensure that we ALWAYS call exit
exit(exit_code);
```

Then I have a bash script which actually makes the call to MATLAB and prints the log output and returns the same error code that was returned from MATLAB

```
# runtests.sh
LOGFILE=log.txt

matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -minimize -wait -logfile "$LOGFILE" -r 'runtests';
CODE=$?

cat "$LOGFILE"

exit $CODE
```

The added benefit here is that my users can run the tests exactly as GITLAB CI runs them on their own machines.

And then my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is quite simple

```
test1:
  script:
  - "runtests.sh"
```

Answer (score 2):

For this answer I assume you mean that the `matlab ...` line fails and this the `type matlab-output.txt` line doesn't run.

Since we dont know whats in your `Model` script/function, but you could try wrapping it in a `try/catch`.

e.g.

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -minimize -wait -logfile matlab-output.txt -r "try; Model; end;"
```

If you have a `exit` command in your Model file you may need to force Matlab to exit if it errors:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -minimize -wait -logfile matlab-output.txt -r "try; Model; catch; quit force; end;"
```

You could also put the try/catch inside your `Model.m` file

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question, you want the line "type matlab-output.txt" to run either when you have a failure or not. Considering that you have one job with several lines, and each of them can fail, all you can do is to create a second job, or a post-job that apparently you want to run even when failure occurs.

For example, according to the [documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html), you could have another job that you can run always:

```
stages:
 - build
 - postbuild

before_script:

test1:
 stage: build
 script:
   - matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -minimize -wait -logfile matlab-output.txt -r Model
typematlab:
  stage: postbuild
  script:
   - type matlab-output.txt
  when: always
```

If you have multiple jobs, I would advise you to separate the jobs in more stages.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use CON as an output file? I.e.

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -minimize -wait -logfile CON -r Model
```

Comment: that's no different to how I do things